# Why does STRAFTER return blank data in json binding in angular?

Tags: json, string, sparql

I am using angular to bind the results of a SPARQL query.

It works nicely until I attempt to bind data returned from queries using the SPARQL "STRAFTER" or "REPLACE" functions (code below) which returns blank data in $scope. But the same query works fine if I run it directly from Fuseki control panel with output set to json.

I am using Fuseki Server 1-1.1.2 endpoint (SPARQL 1.1).

Here is the query that returns expected data in Fuseki server:

```
SELECT  (strafter(str(?class),"#") AS ?className) (COUNT(?s) AS ?count ) 
{ ?s a ?class } 
GROUP BY ?class ORDER BY DESC(?count)
```

Here is the HTML/angular code using the same query in a "$http.get" call with response to be bound in angular coming back as blank:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="queryCtrl"><table>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in results">
    <td>{{x.class.value}}</td>
    <td>{{x.count.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('queryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   var query = encodeURIComponent("SELECT (strafter(str(?class), "#") AS ?    className) (COUNT(?s) AS ?count) {?s a ?class} GROUP BY ?class ORDER BY DESC(?    count)");
   var endpoint = "http://localhost:3030/dataset/query";
   $scope.results = [];
   $http.get("http://localhost:3030/dataset/query?    query="+query+"&output=json")
   .success(function (response) {
    $scope.results = response.results.bindings;
    /* for debugging*/
    if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {
       // console is available, write message if something has happened
       console.log(response.results);
    }
   });

});
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is happening please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this maybe a string quote problem as you `"` string is terminated by the `"` in front of `#`. So try:

```
var query = encodeURIComponent('SELECT (strafter(str(?class),"#") AS ?className) (COUNT(?s) AS ?count ) WHERE { ?s a ?class } GROUP BY ?class ORDER BY DESC(?count)');
```

Comment: Thanks Jorn. Embarassingly that is exactly what the issue is! I was looking at it so long i couldn't see it! Thanks so much.